# ios5 & JSON: can retrieve data from php file but cannot send to the database

Tags: php, objective-c, json, ios5, database-connection

Changed some things and got some new hints.

in my first project, I have to send some data from an iPad and insert it into a SQL database, running in my computer  (MAMP). At the moment, I am trying to send only to strings, "city" and "country". Actually, can't solve two problems
**a)Downloaded de SBJSON 3,1, added the classes to my project, imported `sbjson.h` and wrote the code:**

*Under each `NSLog` I wrote what I got:*

```
#import "SBJson.h"
…
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"surname",@"address",@"email",@"city",@"country",@"gender",@"phone",@"age",@"store",@"time", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:name.text,surname.text,address.text,email.text,city.text,country.text,genderLabel,phone.text,age.text,storeCity,lapTime, nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.111/*****acing/prueba.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSLog(@"jsonData: %@",jsonData);//1

jsonData: <7b227469 6d65223a 2230313a 30373a30 35222c22 61646472 65737322 3a224d61 78696d69 6c69616e 74726173 73652c20 32222c22 6e616d65 223a224f 74746f22 2c226369 7479223a 224dc39c 4e434845 4e222c22 67656e64 6572223a 224d616c 65222c22 70686f6e 65223a22 2b343935 35353232 32323333 222c2265 6d61696c 223a226f 74746f40 64657574 63686c61 6e642e64 65222c22 7375726e 616d6522 3a225072 656d696e 67657222 2c22636f 756e7472 79223a22 4745524d 414e5922 2c226167 65223a22 3630222c 2273746f 7265223a 224dc39c 4e434845 4e227d>


NSLog(@"jsonLength: %d",jsonData.length);//2
223   

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:nil];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"response: %@",response);  //3

{"time":"01:07:05","address":"Maximiliantrasse, 2","name":"Otto","city":"MÜNCHEN","gender":"Male","phone":"+49555222233","email":"otto@deutchland.de","surname":"Preminger","country":"GERMANY","age":"60","store":"MÜNCHEN"}
```

**b)I know nothing about php, and searching the web I wrote in "prueba.php". MySQL is connected to php and I can insert values with a form, but I don't know how to get the data (if it arrives to the php file o.O) and insert the values into the database.**

```
<?php

$hostname_ndb = "localhost";
$database_ndb = "PepeRacing";
$username_ndb = "root";
$password_ndb = "rona5lda";
$ndb = mysql_connect($hostname_ndb, $username_ndb, $password_ndb) or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db($database_ndb) or die("Could not connect to the database");

//get file 
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $body;

$datosJSON = json_decode($body);
print_r($datosJSON);
$datosJSON=utf8_encode($datosJSON);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (city,country,name) VALUES ('{$datosJSON['city']}','{$datosJSON['country']}','{$datosJSON['name']}')");
?>
```

**But if I use the following:**

```
<?php  
if($_POST) {
echo "recibo un paquetito- POST";
//recibo los datos y los descodifico con PHP
$misDatosJSON = json_decode($_POST["jsonData"]);
//debería haber una salida con los datos recibidos, no?
print_r($misDatosJSON);
$salida="";
$salida .="something: " .$misDatosJSON[1];
echo $salida;
}else{
echo "got nothing";
}
?>
```

The ouput is "got nothing"

It seems clear that POST method does not work, any idea to solve it?

Thank you for reading and for your help!

Comment: I don't think it is wise to stuff al that code inside a button :), it's going to block  you main thread. Let's make it simple, you don't post the data directly to the Mysql DB, but make a request to the php that will add it to the DB. I don't see any  GET variables, are you making a request or not?

Comment: My intention is to send the saved data  (Core Data) at a given moment. This is my first app and want to be certain the app connects and sends data. Is there a way to insert the values into the DB without the php file? Thanks

Comment: Changes made in objective-c and php.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, remove all HTML tags, such as ,, closing tags etc from the PHP file.. You are sending headers, header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');, after code was already sent to the browser. This is bad programming practice.

Additionally, the code you have supplied for PHP, will only get data from the database, not insert.

To insert, you would need to do something like:

```
$data_to_insert = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (city,country) VALUES ('{$data_to_insert['city']}','{$data_to_insert['country']}')");
```

The above will decode your $_POST json string, assign the array key/values and then insert into the database.

Comment: Yes,that the php code gets data, was the only one I knew :). Thank you for the code and programming tips provided.

Comment: Intercepting the connection: Request URL:http://localhost/../prueba.php
**Request Method:GET**